# Is content-type "text/xml; charset=utf-8" wrong?

Tags: java, xml, scala, http, utf-8

I am making an HttpRequest and I am specifying Content-Type as follows but my code review by Senior Developers gets rejected.

```
val request = RequestBuilder.post
      .setUri(metaData("serviceUri"))
      .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
      .setEntity(input)
      .build
```

They mention error like:

```
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

However, I do not receive these errors when I run my code on the local machine.
Am I missing something?
Also, I checked on the internet at many places and this is considered correct: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

Comment: have you tried UTF-8?

Comment: Are you sure the URL accepts this format? And the web server?

Comment: Yes I tried with UTF-8 and it works. Also I receive a response from server with "text/xml; charset=utf-8" . I think it might have to do something with coding standard.

Comment: "java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: **text/xml; charset=utf-8** " - I suspect somehow the whole string is being tried to be used as charset name. I would say, the error is not on your side. Seniors should put some effort in debugging before rejecting correct code :(

Comment: Does doing `.build` actually work? Shouldn't it be `.build()`?

Comment: This is scala code so it works. Maybe I should have been more clear.

Comment: More clear than tagging it "scala"? Also, "val" should have been a hint... But back to topic: My suggestion is that you contact your manager if seniors keep on rejecting your code and refuse to go into it after having talked to them. It makes you waste time on chasing a bug, where there is none. Your content type field is absolutely complying to specification. The bug is in the code that works off that field value and that is quite obvious from the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

You have written it correctly, but try to add the code below too

```
.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

To explicitly set the encoding.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I am sorry, I am not a pro, but if I were in this case, I would try these:

-writing charset like this "UTF-8" (uppercase),
-or instead of putting ";" after text/xml, just putting "," (comma)
-or try to use setHeader option

Again, I am not a pro, these are all I could found by searching on the internet just now about the error you got. I hope any of this may helpful to you.

Comment: "*writing charset like this "UTF-8" (uppercase)*" - makes no difference, as media type parameters are case-insensitive; "*instead of putting ";" after text/xml, just putting "," (comma)*" - is syntaxically wrong. A media type is separated from its parameters by a semicolon only, and the parameters are separated from each other by semicolons, too.